# Preloader v-cloak not showing text loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have in css:

```
[v-cloak]::before { content: "loading…"; display: block; text-align: center; width: 300px; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 60px; }
```

When page loading, I don't get `loading..`. Why? I get white background.. I need do preloader v-cloak, show on user, that page is loading..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element is inserted as the ***first child*** of the `[v-cloak]` element, which is ***hidden***.

The fix would be to create an adjacent element for the loading indicator, and apply the intended CSS there:

```
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>
<div id="loader"></div>

<style>
[v-cloak] + #loader::before {
  /* ... */
}
</style>
```

```js
setTimeout(() => new Vue({ el: '#app' }), 1500)
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

[v-cloak] + #loader::before {
  content: "loading…";
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <p>Hello Vue.js!</p>
</div>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the example from the documentation:

CSS:
`[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}`

.vue:
`<div v-cloak>
    Loading...
</div>`

Comment: This will display the "Loading..." message after the section has rendered, which probably not what you want.